# IntelliJ Error Stripe Mark scala / sbt

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, syntax-error

In PHPStorm I have these error stripe marks when a file contains an error:

[image: PHPStorm]

But in IntelliJ (SBT, Scala) I don't get any, even though the inspection clearly contains errors in the file:
[image: IntelliJ]

Is there something I'm missing (setting in IntelliJ)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error stripe marking was introduced in the Scala plugin 2017.1.3. The feature is disabled by default, but you can turn it on by going to *Preferences / Languages & Frameworks / Scala / Project View / Highlight nodes with errors*

Comment: Thanks. I assumed it was an existing feature, but I first had to update.

Comment: i can't turn it off any more.